# SSRS Series Grouping

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, grouping, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a bar chart where the X-Axis has grouping on Category and subcategory, the issue i have is that when adding a series and grouping that on say Category each subcategory then has 3 points(for each category returned) plotted rather than the one for that subcategory within the category. Hopefully the image might be a bit clearer. I only want the one bar and for it to line up with the subcategory axis label. I can do this via time entry but then all bars are the same colour.

SSRS Series Grouping

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Keep both the Category Groups on your chart, but remove the Series Group. This means the chart will only expect one bar per category rather than three.

You can restore the colour-coding for each subcategory by using an expression. Go to the Series Properties, and in the Fill options use an expression like this for the `Color`:

```
=IIF(Fields!GRP1.Value = "Dynamic NAV", "YellowGreen",
IIF(Fields!GRP1.Value = "Hand Held Terminal", "MediumVioletRed",
IIF(Fields!GRP1.Value = "Other", "Orange", "Black")))
```